# How do I scrape text from a website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

How do I scrape text from a website using Selenium?
I need to get an inner text from a website. I'm using the newest Python and Selenium, all up to date. I also have pyautogui.

Here is what I need to scrape:

```
<span  class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="addKeysInMatch(characterMatch.bad)">Gorgeous Geodes Glowed</span>
```

I don't know part of the text though, the "Gorgeous Geodes Glowed" is what I don't know, and I need to find that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
titles_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding']")
titles = [x.text for x in titles_element]
titles = []
for x in titles_element:
    titles.append(x.text)
print(titles)
```

The Gorgeous Geodes Glowed is the text that appears after the span class is Identified. So every time this class appears it will print out the following text.

Comment: whenever i do that it comes up with []

Comment: Can I check out the URL to see what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: it needs a username and password

Comment: If it’s free I’ll create my own, if not, just change your password... the only other thing I can think of is you’re behind a firewall and implicit/explicit waits aren’t working because firewalls have a beautiful way to jam them up. Whenever you get to wherever you need to go, put a time.sleep() line in and see if it changes anything